# How to locate and type something in the textbox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
public class testFluent {   

WebDriver driver;   
    @Before
        public void setUp(){        
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();}

         @Test
        public void myFirstFluent(){
        WebElement element;
        driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");         
        element = myDynamicElement(By.id("//*[@id='p_13838465-p']"));
        System.out.println("Element found");
        }

        public WebElement myDynamicElement(final By locator){

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

            WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebElement, WebDriver>(){

                public WebElement apply(WebDriver drv){
                    return drv.findElement(By.id(locator));
                }
            });

                return element;
        }

    }
```

I am unable to locate and ends with Error.

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: The method until(Function) in the type Wait is not applicable for the arguments (new Function(){}) Function cannot be resolved to a type
>
> The method id(String) in the type By is not applicable for the arguments (By) at com.junit.qa.testFluent.myDynamicElement(testFluent.java:49)

Comment: Telling us the error is usually helpful.

Comment: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,T>) in the type Wait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (new Function<WebElement,WebDriver>(){})
 Function cannot be resolved to a type
 The method id(String) in the type By is not applicable for the arguments (By)

 at com.junit.qa.testFluent.myDynamicElement(testFluent.java:49)

Comment: You are passing in the wrong parameters to the method call.

Comment: can you please show me how to do that, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For wait you can use something like this

```
    private boolean wAit(String match)
    {
    try
        {
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated (By.xpath(match)));
        return true;
        }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

You can create the above method and use it where ever you need to wait for an element.   for example

if want a write something in the textbox and want to wait for the text box to load

```
wAit(" xpath of the textbox here")
driver.findelements... sendkeys()..
```

If you want you can change the locator type and increase/decrease the time limit also

Comment: @ Sriram thank you, your snippet certainly helped a lot.

Comment: @SabbirSohan : Glad it was of help. Did this resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps u..

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;  


public class yahoo {  

     FirefoxDriver Driver=null;
     WebDriverWait wait = null;



     @BeforeTest  
     public void start(){  
      Driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
     }  

    @Test 
     public void Test() throws InterruptedException{   
      wait=new WebDriverWait(Driver,90); 
      System.out.println("Loading yahoo search page");  
      Driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");  
      System.out.println("Yahoo search page loaded fine");  
      WebElement text=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='p_13838465-p']")));
      text.sendKeys("selenium");
      Thread.sleep(5000);

     }  

     @AfterTest  
     public void close(){  
     Driver.quit();   
     }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your `By.id` statement, it looks like you have passed an XPath instead of just the id. So this:

```
element = myDynamicElement(By.id("//*[@id='p_13838465-p']")); //this locator is an XPath
```

should become this:

```
element = myDynamicElement(By.id('p_13838465-p')); //this is just the ID
```

However, if this ID is dynamically generated, then it won't work reliably, and you may need to considering finding it by a different locator.

Then, once you've identified the element, to type in it, you use `.sendKeys("your text here")`, like this:

```
element.sendKeys("your text here");
```

or you could combine it into one line by skipping the `element =` part and just say:

```
myDynamicElement(By.id('p_13838465-p')).sendKeys("your text here");
```

Answer (score 0):

> I encountered with same issue and couldn't find any solution for it.Then i tried WebDriverWait instead of FluentWait and it worked for me

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 60);
wait.withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
          WebElement ele=driver.findElement(locator);
          if(ele==null)
              return false;
          else
          {
              System.out.println("WebElement found");
              return true;
          }

      }
    });
```