# C# catch exception returning from function not in process?

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm currently running into an issue within a loop, basically the first process works perfectly when I call -

Example of code:

```
public static void Search()
    {

        var Lines = File.ReadLines(@"in.txt").Take(1000).ToList();

        var query = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Lines);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));
        IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("search")));

        if (driver.FindElements(By.Name("search")).Count != 0)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("search")).SendKeys(query);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            driver.FindElement(By.Name("submitbtn")).Click();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Getting Results");

            if (driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody")).Count != 0)
            {
                Results();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Results()
    {
        try
        {

            WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            IWebElement element1 = wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.TagName("result")));


            if (driver.FindElements(By.TagName("result")).Count != 0)
            {

                var element2 = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("text"));

                foreach (var text in element2)
                {
                    var data = text.GetAttribute("outerHTML");

                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("output.txt", data + Environment.NewLine);

                }

                driver.Navigate().Refresh();

                Search();

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No results");

                driver.Navigate().Refresh();

                Search();
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to get results");
            driver.Close();
            Load();
        }
    }
```

but upon returning to `Search()`

for a second attempt, which is called within Results

```
    Search();
```

after successfully processing `Results();`

during the second Search process, Results() catch exception throws, ie

```
   Failed to get results
```

However Results() function isn't in process :S as I called back to Search(), so my conclusion is I never exited from Results and it's still processing and after 30 seconds of not finding the element it throws an exception, but how do I call for Search() again for a second attempt & exit Results()?

Answer (score 0):

I think this two lines throwing an exception:

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
IWebElement element1 = wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.TagName("result")));
```

From my perpective you don't need them since you have already:

```
if (driver.FindElements(By.TagName("result")).Count != 0)
```

If you are not sure, that results will be in `DOM` quickly, you can add a pause or surround also with `try/catch` block like this:

```
try {
    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    IWebElement element1 = wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.TagName("result")));
}catch {
    Console.WriteLine("No results");
}
if (driver.FindElements(By.TagName("result")).Count != 0)
```

***PS:*** I'm not sure, that you need `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable`, since you are not clicking on the element. You can use `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeVisible` for example.

Comment: Yes I did assume wait1.until element exists was throwing the exception, but it's essential for that element to be clickable/visible before I continue with the rest of requests code, it works perfectly the first time I call the function, but when I return to Search(); obviously the element " result " is no longer visible/clickable and therefore after 30 seconds it throws an exception.. But I thought upon returning to search(); from results(); it would have exited results();? So the solution would be I assume is to successfully end results function then return to search, but how would I do that?

Comment: but with my suggestion you are returning to search()

Comment: the problem is even when i return to search(), results() still looks for the element result, its asif it doesnt exit re

Comment: argh seems like other people had similar issues, seems like selenium/c# executes next process within function before finishing " SendKeys " string.. :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945082/webdriver-sendkeysinput-does-not-complete-before-sendkeyskeys-return

there's quite a few more regarding sendkeys not finsihing input before continuing to next task