# SeleniumWebdriver_How To select particular link when from search results

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Am new in selenium webdriver & right now I'm struggling at one point for that I need some guidelines. I'm searching employee records in search results &for require employee record I have set excel sheet for input purpose so I'm able to do that successfully but now the issue is that when a search returns me the require results I'm not able to click on that record can someone suggest me what I'm doing wrong .
I have designed below code for that                                                                                             `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#txtSearchKeyword")).sendKeys(Sheet.getCell(3, i).getContents());
        driver.findElement(By.name("")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='button'])[8]")).click();`

so per above script I'm able to search employee records by providing input from excel sheet but not able to click that records to move forward. any suggestion on these will really appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us the stacktrace. What error does it throw?

Comment: Hi Sriram, i havnt got any error. im not able to click at the records in search result. im providing my input through one of excel sheet and how can i make script to clik that single records out of many different

Comment: As Raghuveer Pointed out, try adding Wait statement. You can refer this link for reference . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186851/how-to-locate-and-type-something-in-the-textbox/23192948#23192948

Answer (score 1):

@Amit once you click on search give some wait condition and then click on the link which you are expecting. because the code gets executed line by line while the page loads it is searching for the link to click , so give some wait until you see the link and then click on the link.