# Unable to identify a static dropdown

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a webpage where I am unable to identify a static drop down.

`<select name = "homeURL" tabIndex = "4" class = "storeId" >..</select>`

I tried to identify it using below mentioned code using Select class

`Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("homeURL")));
dropdown.selectByIndex(2);`

I am getting the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with name == homeURL (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799545/selenium-web-driver-findelementby-name-and-headless-browser

Answer (score 0):

It could be a various amount of different factors. Such as the web driver, iframe, or even how long it takes for the page to render. Please consider the following links:

Web Driver: [Selenium InternetExplorerDriver unable to find element that is clearly there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754402/selenium-internetexplorerdriver-unable-to-find-element-that-is-clearly-there)

Iframe:
[Selenium WebDriver: unable to locate element inside iframe using TinyMCE editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873874/selenium-webdriver-unable-to-locate-element-inside-iframe-using-tinymce-editor)

Page rendering issue:
[Selenium Unable to Find Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832266/selenium-unable-to-find-element)

Please consider looking at the version of your web driver, selenium, and installed browsers.

Comment: Thank you. It was Page  Rendering issue.